# Typescript: Extending generic classes gives a ton of errors

Tags: typescript, collections, libraries

I started using typescript recently, and I'm using [collect.js](https://github.com/ecrmnn/collect.js) along with other libraries (pinia-orm among them).

This one is a replica of Laravel collections in JS with support for TS. The type of the class is:

```
Collection<Item>
```

As far as I know, it can be extended, so I did it:

```
// CustomCollection.js
import {Collection} from 'collect.js';
import CustomModel from './CustomModel';

export default class CustomCollection extends Collection<CustomModel> {
    constructor(models?: CustomModel[]) {
        super(models);
    }
}

// CustomModel.js:
import {Model, ModelFields} from 'pinia-orm';

export default class CustomModel extends Model {
    static entity = 'custom';
    declare id: number;
    declare name: string;
    declare description: string;

    static fields(): ModelFields {
        return {
            id: this.number(0),
            name: this.string(''),
            description: this.string(''),
        };
    }
}

// using it:
const collection = new CustomCollection();
```

Done in this way it's giving me a few more errors than I expected:

- TS2314: Generic type 'Collection' requires 1 type argument(s) (I tried and still throws the same error)
- TS2339: Property 'first' does not exist on type 'MyCustomCollection' (a method from the parent class
- TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0 (this happens when I'm creating a new collection without parameters)

Some questions I can throw are:

1. Do I have to make it generic too when it's supposed to be specific for this item/type?
2. Why is it requiring parameters even if I make them optional? This happens at compile time
3. Why doesn't it recognize any of the methods in the parent class? Is it related to the fact that they're added to the prototype of a function instead of being a class?

Some guidance here would be much appreciated, I'm starting to be lost here... Thank you!

Comment: ① Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates what you're talking about when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs.  Ideally any third-party or private type or value definitions should be replaced or included as plaintext and not just referenced via link, reduced to the minimum amount of definitions that still exhibits your issue.  ② Please ask a single well-defined question; multiple questions in a single post risks having it closed as needing more focus.

Comment: @jcalz I just edited it, but to be honest there isn't much more code that I can add, that's all I have and that bit is throwing all those errors. As per the questions, I guess they can all be summarized in "what am I doing wrong to not be able to extend a simple class without all those errors?"

Comment: Please [edit] the question to summarize the question as a single question so that it's in the post itself and not just a comment.  Note that [I can't reproduce your issues with that code](https://tsplay.dev/mb3AEW) so we need more debugging details to possibly help.

Comment: @jcalz well I can't reproduce it there either, even though I moved all the imports to the first lines it keeps saying that "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module". I'm not sure what else can I provide, can you please be more specific of what is needed? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in a good position to give such advice; without a [mre] I'm working blindly on some problem that exists only in some remote environment to which I have no access or insight.  Maybe someone else with more ability to do that will come along to help?  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I must have misexplained, what I was asking for in my last comment is what exactly is required for a "minimal reproducible example". I have provided all the involved code, there is no more, that's why I'm confused, I don't know what else can I provide. But thank you anyways